# I am not able to locate an Element from a dropdown and it's showing NoSuchElementException is someone can help me out what's wrong i entered here

Tags: selenium-webdriver

On Firefox webdriver:

```
WebDriverWait wait4 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='introjsTicketsFilters']/gc-filters/div[3]/gc-dropdown/div/div/div")));
//Action class to pick the value from dorp down     
WebElement mnuElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='introjsTicketsFilters']/gc-filters/div[3]/gc-dropdown/div/div/div"));

WebElement submnuElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='ng-binding' and contains(text(),'17/18')]"));

Actions actionT = new Actions(driver);

actionT.moveToElement(mnuElement).clickAndHold(submnuElement).click().build().perform();
```

Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   .//span[@class='ng-binding' and contains(text(),'17/18')]

Main Element focussed on the dropdown

[image]

subelement
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You use **"and"** Expression in your XPATH.**In AND expression**, two conditions are used, both conditions should be true to find the element. It fails to find element if any one condition is false.

> I am sure that "ng-bind" class use on your html page at somewhere in
>   different span tags.

If both conditions are satisfied than it will work.

Use OR Expression instead of AND

**OR Expression:**

In OR expression, two conditions are used, whether 1st condition OR 2nd condition should be true. It is also applicable if any one condition is true or maybe both. Means any one condition should be true to find the element.

```
WebElement submnuElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='ng-binding' OR contains(text(),'17/18')]"));
```

If this solution works please post your HTML code.

Comment: Hi @Dhru thanks for investigating the issue i used below code and it worked for me.I got to know the Dev's has refactored that page and the new class wasn't merged.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait4 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//gc-dropdown//div[*[contains(text(), 'Season')]]")));
  
WebElement mnuElement;
WebElement submnuElement;
mnuElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//gc-dropdown//div[*[contains(text(), 'Season')]]"));
mnuElement.click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
submnuElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//gc-dropdown//*[contains(@class, 'dropdown-item')]//*[text() = '17/18']"));
submnuElement.click();
Thread.sleep(3000);

Comment: @RituNehra That's great Please upvote and mark it as answer if it works for you.